# Is the category of quasi-coherent sheaves on a concentrated stack locally finitely presentable?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, stacks

Let's call an Artin stack $X$ *concentrated* iff it is quasi-compact and quasi-separated (the latter usually being included in the definition of an Artin stack). The category of quasi-coherent sheaves $\mathrm{Qcoh}(X)$ is a locally presentable abelian Grothendieck category.

**Question.** Is $\mathrm{Qcoh}(X)$ locally finitely presentable?
In other words, is every quasi-coherent sheaf a directed colimit of quasi-coherent sheaves of finite presentation?

This is known if $X$ is a concentrated scheme (EGA I, 6.9.12). It is also known when $X$ is noetherian (Lurie's [Tannaka duality](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0412/0412266v2.pdf), Lemma 3.9). Is anything known about the general case?

Added: In his work about [noetherian approximation](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0904/0904.0227v2.pdf) (Theorem A + Prop. 2.7), David Rydh has shown that this is true for concentrated Deligne-Mumford stacks.